# Is it possible to migrate embed h2 database to PostgreSQL database with data in WSO2 identity server 5.10

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server

We are  using default h2 database in wso2 identity server 5.10. we want to migrate h2 database to postgres data base with complete old data.
I  did not find any link for migrating with data.

Can you please help on it.

Answer (score 0):

> I did not find any link for migrating with data.

WSO2 does not support migrating data between RDBMSs. You might have to find a third party tool for that.